# Tomcat8 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: tomcat8, guacamole

my url is http://localhost:8080/guacamole it returns

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /guacamole

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.30 (Ubuntu)
```

and for url localhost:8080 it shows

```
It works !

If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup Tomcat successfully. Congratulations!

This is the default Tomcat home page. It can be found on the local filesystem at: /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/index.html

Tomcat8 veterans might be pleased to learn that this system instance of Tomcat is installed with CATALINA_HOME in /usr/share/tomcat8 and CATALINA_BASE in /var/lib/tomcat8, following the rules from /usr/share/doc/tomcat8-common/RUNNING.txt.gz.

You might consider installing the following packages, if you haven't already done so:

tomcat8-docs: This package installs a web application that allows to browse the Tomcat 8 documentation locally. Once installed, you can access it by clicking here.

tomcat8-examples: This package installs a web application that allows to access the Tomcat 8 Servlet and JSP examples. Once installed, you can access it by clicking here.

tomcat8-admin: This package installs two web applications that can help managing this Tomcat instance. Once installed, you can access the manager webapp and the host-manager webapp.

NOTE: For security reasons, using the manager webapp is restricted to users with role "manager-gui". The host-manager webapp is restricted to users with role "admin-gui". Users are defined in /etc/tomcat8/tomcat-users.xml.
```

but i need apache tom server site